# Peak value of sine wave for capacitively coupled inverting amplifier

Tags: voltage, capacitive, coupling, inverting-amplifier, dc-offset

I was working on question 2.23(a) and there is asked what input voltage is needed in order to ensure that the output does not clip. The clipping limits are +10 to -10 V.

I solved that, and, basically, what I did was that first I nulled the input voltage and found the output voltage due to the offset voltage source connected to the positive terminal of the opamp and then I nulled the offset source and found the contribution of the input voltage to the output voltage (superposition) and then I added the two (output voltage contributions) and put them equal to 10, which is the saturation voltage for the opamp.

However, my answer to question 2.23 is not correct. So I wanted to ask: if I am not doing it correctly, how do I do it then?
Here is the circuit I used:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV3clz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This site has a built-in schematic editor. It's a lot easier to use than editing an existing image!

Comment: What values did you get?

Comment: I got 7 mV for the max amplitude of input sine wave in order to avoid output clipping. But the answer indicated is 10 mV